# Count if array in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get a new column with the number of columns that are positive for every index row

this is what the data frame looks like:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    |   week1 |   week2 |   week3 |   week4 |   week5 |
+====+=========+=========+=========+=========+=========+
|  0 |      70 |      60 |      50 |     -40 |     -30 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 |      50 |      10 |     -20 |     -40 |     -60 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  2 |     -80 |     -90 |    -100 |    -110 |    -120 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  3 |     110 |      80 |      70 |      60 |      50 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  4 |      10 |     -50 |     -70 |     -80 |     -90 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

and this is the result that I'm looking for, a new column that counts the number of weeks if the number is positive

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+------------------+
|    |   week1 |   week2 |   week3 |   week4 |   week5 |   POSITIVE WEEKS |
+====+=========+=========+=========+=========+=========+==================+
|  0 |      70 |      60 |      50 |     -40 |     -30 |                3 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+------------------+
|  1 |      50 |      10 |     -20 |     -40 |     -60 |                2 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+------------------+
|  2 |     -80 |     -90 |    -100 |    -110 |    -120 |                0 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+------------------+
|  3 |     110 |      80 |      70 |      60 |      50 |                5 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+------------------+
|  4 |      10 |     -50 |     -70 |     -80 |     -90 |                1 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Positive Weeks'] = df.gt(0).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks! I found out that this line of code works as well

    cols = df.columns
    df['COUNT'] = df[df[cols] > 0].count(axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

@rhug123 has a great answer.

Just want to show a different way to do it in a `dplyr`-like way:

```py
>>> from datar.all import *
>>> df = tribble(
...     f.week1, f.week2, f.week3, f.week4, f.week5,
...          70,      60,      50,     -40,     -30,
...          50,      10,     -20,     -40,     -60,
...         -80,     -90,    -100,    -110,    -120,
...         110,      80,      70,      60,      50,
...          10,     -50,     -70,     -80,     -90,
... )
>>> df >> rowwise() >> mutate(
...     POSITIVE_WEEKS=sum(as_integer(c_across(starts_with("week")) > 0))
... )
    week1   week2   week3   week4   week5  POSITIVE_WEEKS
  <int64> <int64> <int64> <int64> <int64>         <int64>
0      70      60      50     -40     -30               3
1      50      10     -20     -40     -60               2
2     -80     -90    -100    -110    -120               0
3     110      80      70      60      50               5
4      10     -50     -70     -80     -90               1
>>> # or
>>> df >> rowwise() >> mutate(
...     POSITIVE_WEEKS=sum(if_else(c_across(starts_with("week")) > 0, 1, 0))
... )
    week1   week2   week3   week4   week5  POSITIVE_WEEKS
  <int64> <int64> <int64> <int64> <int64>         <int64>
0      70      60      50     -40     -30               3
1      50      10     -20     -40     -60               2
2     -80     -90    -100    -110    -120               0
3     110      80      70      60      50               5
4      10     -50     -70     -80     -90               1
```

[`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) is a package that ports dplyr and related R packages in python. I am the author of the package.